# Why is EC2 instance store volume not mounted?

Tags: amazon-ebs, amazon-ami, aws-ec2

I created an AWS EC2 instance of type `g5.2xlage` with [Deep Learning Base GPU AMI (Ubuntu 20.04)](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-gci6c7xxli2wc). This instance type has an [instance store volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/instance-store-volumes.html). After first start, the [ephemeral instance store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) was mounted, but every 2 or 3 restarts (or stop and start), the volume isn't mounted.

**Good case**

If the volume is mounted, I can see it with `lsblk`:

```
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                  7:0    0  33.3M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
loop1                  7:1    0  24.9M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/7628
loop2                  7:2    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2066
loop3                  7:3    0  91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
loop4                  7:4    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2812
loop5                  7:5    0  40.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20671
loop6                  7:6    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2105
loop7                  7:7    0  67.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/20326
nvme0n1              259:0    0    80G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1          259:3    0    80G  0 part /
nvme2n1              259:1    0 419.1G  0 disk
└─vg.01-lv_ephemeral 253:0    0 419.1G  0 lvm  /opt/dlami/nvme
nvme1n1              259:2    0    75G  0 disk /mnt/data
```

and I can see in `syslog`, that the script `/opt/aws/dlami/bin/nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh` is executed:

```
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[558]: This instance type has (1) device(s) for instance store: (/dev/nvme2n1)
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[558]: LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) does not exist
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[558]: Creating LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral)
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[878]:   Physical volume "/dev/nvme2n1" successfully created.
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[889]:   Volume group "vg.01" successfully created
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[925]:   Ignoring stripesize argument with single stripe.
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[925]:   Logical volume "lv_ephemeral" created.
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[558]: LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) created successfully
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[558]: Found LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) in state (a)
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[558]: Found LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) FS type ()
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[558]: Formatting LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) with FS type (ext4)
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: Discarding device blocks:      4096/109862912#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010                   #010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010done
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: Creating filesystem with 109862912 4k blocks and 27467776 inodes
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: Filesystem UUID: 44fddd50-9a7b-4eec-8e68-2fd5def18526
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: Superblock backups stored on blocks:
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: #01132768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: #0114096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: #011102400000
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: Allocating group tables:    0/3353#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010         #010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010done
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: Writing inode tables:    0/3353#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010         #010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010done
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1333]: Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information:    0/3353#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010         #010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010done
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[558]: LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) formatted successfully
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[558]: LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) not mounted, mounting on (/opt/dlami/nvme)
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[1529]: mount: /dev/mapper/vg.01-lv_ephemeral mounted on /opt/dlami/nvme.
nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh[558]: LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) mounted successfully
```

**Failing case**

If the volume is not mounted, I can see it with `lsblk`:

```
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                  7:0    0  33.3M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
loop1                  7:1    0  24.9M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/7628
loop2                  7:2    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2066
loop3                  7:3    0  91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
loop4                  7:4    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2812
loop5                  7:5    0  40.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20671
loop6                  7:6    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2105
loop7                  7:7    0  67.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/20326
nvme0n1              259:0    0    80G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1          259:3    0    80G  0 part /
nvme2n1              259:1    0 419.1G  0 disk
nvme1n1              259:2    0    75G  0 disk /mnt/data
```

**Research**

- If I run the script `/opt/aws/dlami/bin/nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh` on the failing instance manually, the partition is created and mounted.
- If I run the script `/opt/aws/dlami/bin/nvme_ephemeral_drives.sh` on the good instance manually, nothing is changed.

  ```
  This instance type has (1) device(s) for instance store: (/dev/nvme2n1)
  LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) already exists
  Found LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) in state (a)
  Found LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) FS type (ext4)
  LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) already formatted with FS type (ext4)
  LVM (/dev/vg.01/lv_ephemeral) already mounted on (/opt/dlami/nvme)
  ```

**Question**

Why is my ephemeral instance store not mounted every time?